# Can't transform results of Eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm building an API in Laravel to learn how to do such a thing. I'm following a Laracasts course to do this, but I'm having some troubles with the parts I want to do for myself.

Currently, I have this function in my controller. It fetches data from two tables and then returns it.

```
public function lesson($userid)
{

    $lessons = DB::table('lessons')
                ->join('userlessons', 'lessons.id', '=', 'userlessons.lessonsid')
                ->select('lessons.name', 'lessons.seen')
                ->where('userlessons.userid','=', $userid)
                ->get();

    return $this->respondWithPagination($lessons, [

        'data' => $this->LessonTransformer->transformCollection($lessons)

    ]);

}
```

And LessonTransformer is this:

```
class LessonTransformer extends Transformer 
{

    public function transformCollection($items)
    {

        return array_map([$this, 'transform'], $items);

    }

    public function transform($item)
    {

        return [

            'name' => $item['name'],
            'seen' => (bool) $item['seen']

        ];

    }

}
```

I tried a lot of solutions, some smart, some stupid. But I keep getting this error: `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get such error, probably you need to change:

```
return [    
    'name' => $item['name'],
    'seen' => (bool) $item['seen']    
];
```

into:

```
return [    
    'name' => $item->name,
    'seen' => (bool) $item->seen
];
```

but you haven't showed in which line error appear so it's only a guess